# in drupal language: grep and pipe - list all the findings to avoid overhead & serverperformance issues

Tags: linux, drupal, find, grep

As i have a serous sever performance warning with installing drupal-commons (this is a installation-profile) i now want to reduce the server load.
Why - i get a message when trying to install drupal commons: Too-many-files-open it says!
Well Drupal & modules (ab)uses too many files! 50,000 maximum files and maybe 5000 directories is their goal and that si what they only backup so its in 
So my question: How can i get rid of all those silly translation files or whatever for tiny miny parts of info and 
unnecesary subdivisions; How i can get rid of them!

**Background:** I would expect that file_exists() during the installation(or bootstrap-cycle) is the most expensive built-in PHP function measured as total time spent calling the function for all invocations in a single request.

Well now i try to get rid of all the overhead (especially of the translation-files that are so called - po-files) - and unnecessary files that are contained in the drupal-commons 6.x-2.3 in order to get it runnning on my server.

i want to get rid all those silly translation files or whatever for tiny miny parts of info and unnecesary subdivisions;

How to **search for all those .po-files recursivly** - with GREP i guess ..
**Note**: i do not now where they are!

```
linux-vi17:/home/martin/web_technik/drupal/commons_3_jan_12/commons-6.x-2.3/commons-6.x-2.3 # lsCHANGELOG.txt       
   ._.htaccess          install.php        modules       themes
._CHANGELOG.txt              ._includes           INSTALL.txt        ._profiles    ._update.php
COMMONS_RELEASE_NOTES.txt    includes             ._INSTALL.txt      profiles      update.php
._COMMONS_RELEASE_NOTES.txt  ._index.php          LICENSE.txt        ._robots.txt  UPGRADE.txt
COPYRIGHT.txt                index.php            ._LICENSE.txt      robots.txt    ._UPGRADE.txt
._COPYRIGHT.txt              INSTALL.mysql.txt    MAINTAINERS.txt    ._scripts     ._xmlrpc.php
._cron.php                   ._INSTALL.mysql.txt  ._MAINTAINERS.txt  scripts       xmlrpc.php
cron.php                     INSTALL.pgsql.txt    ._misc             ._sites
.directory                   ._INSTALL.pgsql.txt  misc               sites
.htaccess                    ._install.php        ._modules          ._themes
linux-vi17:/home/martin/web_technik/drupal/commons_3_jan_12/commons-6.x-2.3/commons-6.x-2.3 # grep .po
```

Any way i want to  remove all .po files with one bash command - is this possible

but wait: first of all - i want to find out all the files - and the ni want to list it:
 - since i then know what i rease (/or  remove)

Well - all language translations in Drupal are named with .po -

how to find them with GREP?
How to list them - and subsequently - how to erase them!?

**update:** 
i did the search with

```
find  -type f -name "*.po"
```

. well i found approx 930 files.

afterwards i did remove all them with

```
6.x-2.3 # find -type f -name "*.po" -exec rm -f {} \;
```

a final serach with that code

```
find  -type f -name "*.po"
```

gave no results back so  every po-file was erased!

manym many thanks for the hints.

greetings
zero

Comment: This is confusing. Where are your .po files located? Do you know the base directory? Should it be searched for recursively for .po files?

Comment: yes  you were right! it should be searched for recursively for .po files!!! well i have to clear up the question above! you were 100 % rihgt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to find all files named `*.po` in a directory named `/some/directory`, you can use `find`:

```
find /some/directory -type f -name "*.po"
```

If you want to delete them all in a row (you do have backups, don't you?), then append an action to this command:

```
find /some/directory -type f -name "*.po" -exec rm -f {} \;
```

Replace `/some/directory` with the appropriate value and you should be set.

Comment: If your version of `find` has it, you can use `find /some/directory -type f -name "*.po" -print -delete`

Comment: find  -type f -name "*.po"
linux-vi17:/home/martin/web_technik/drupal/commons_3_jan_12/commons-6.x-2.3/commons-6.x-2.3 # find  -type f -name "*.po"
linux-vi17:/home/martin/web_technik/drupal/commons_3_jan_12/commons-6.x-2.3/commons-6.x-2.3 # find -type f -name "*.po" -exec rm -f {} \;
linux-vi17:/home/martin/web_technik/drupal/commons_3_jan_12/commons-6.x-2.3/commons-6.x-2.3 # find  -type f -name "*.po"

Answer (score 1):

The issue with "too many open files" isn't normally because there are too many files in the filesystem, but because there is a limitation to the amount of files an application or user can have open at one time. This issue has been covered on drupal forums, for example, see this thread to solve it more permanently/nicely:

http://drupal.org/node/474152

A few more links about open files:
http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/linux-procfs-file-descriptors.html
http://blog.thecodingmachine.com/content/solving-too-many-open-files-exception-red5-or-any-other-application